# Login with Facebook in a Google Play >Closed Beta< app

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, facebook-login

I have an app which (at the moment) only have Login through Facebook. Google Play has something called Closed Beta where you can invite a "larger" amount of users into a closed beta test. I'm wondering if there's a way to have a Closed Beta on Google Play without having to make all these users "Test Users" on the Facebook platform to let them login.

Right now I have to invite each and every one, and they have to "Confirm" the request - meaning they have to become Facebook Developers. This is a very inconvenient process for users.

All this would be "solved" if I can make the Facebook app public, but I can't since they require that the app be Live in Google Play (and App Store).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance if this seems silly, we should only need to make users developers on facebook if we are accessing a staging environment in your app. Production environments on facebook should not need developer access.

Comment: Hey! Not sure if there was a question in your statement(?). But right now, I want to be able to let a semi-large group test the app (without making it super-visible to everyone).

Comment: essentially, my question is, do u have a dev environment and a prod environment on facebook? you probably need to look into that since the only time u will need a developer account is when u are using the dev environment

Comment: It's a dev environment and I can't make it production unless I have the app Live on Google Play. And to my knowledge, Facebook can't detect my app as Live when it's in Closed Beta. Thus I'm asking my question.